# What is the best way to hold a sphere and for how long?

Tags: molecular-gastronomy, spherification

I have been playing around with the spherification process. My questions are how long can I hold a sphere and what is the best way to do so??

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, spheres done with the reverse method (calcium solution dipped in alginate) can last up to four days, well refrigerated, and kept submerged in vegetable (soy or canola) oil. I do not know the science behind it, only that it works. For reference, these were spheres made of a carrot-ginger consomme, not certain of specific amounts of calcium chlorate (in the carrot mix) and sodium alginate (bath) used. Note that acidity may play a role in how long spheres will last, and (often) the chemical reaction will continue, albeit slower; on Day 1 we'd have thin membranes with very liquid interiors. By Day 4, the membrane would be perceptibly thicker and the contents more glutinous.